# draw 43 xy scatter drawing using vba in excel

Tags: vba, draw

I need to draw 43 x/y scatter drawing using VBA in excel I developed this code for one drawing and I am not sure how I can apply this to draw the remaining 42 drawing I mean I don't want to change the range of the data manually I need to put this in a for loop or something like this. This is my code

```
Sub draw()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""HBES"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=EN!$G$253:$G$278"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=EN!$H$253:$h$278"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""NHBES"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=EN!$G$253:$G$278"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='EN1'!$g$253:$g$278"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Name = "=""NHBCS"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues = "=EN!$G$253:$G$278"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = "=EN1c!$g$253:$g$278"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Name = "=""HBCS"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).XValues = "=EN!$G$253:$G$278"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Values = "=ENC!$h$253:$h$278"
    With ActiveChart
     'chart name
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Expected Number of Blockages for Pipes Group Two in Condition State One"
     'X axis name
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (Years)"
     'y-axis name
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Expected Number of Blockages"
End With
End Sub
```

Please note that the data is arranged in column so for the next drawing I should change this line from

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=EN!$H$253:$H$278"
```

to be

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=EN!$I$253:$I$278"

and the same for the remaining three series and the x range is constant for all drawing which is

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues = "=EN!$G$253:$G$278"
```

I hope this was clear

thanks in advance

Comment: Why no one is answering? come on guys I don't think its something impossible to do please help

Comment: you could write an array containing the columns and then for the length of the array loop through your code. altering your code would only need the following: "=En!$" & ColArr(i) & "$253:$" & ColArr(i) & "$278". colArr = Arr("A", "B", "C", "D" ...) and I'm recommending doing the following as well: Coll1 = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1), Coll2 = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2) and so on. Little less typing ;)